# I have uneven frame rates on Samsung Galaxy S3 using Cocos2D-X

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, frame-rate

When compiling and running the default project for Cocos2D-X on my Samsung Galaxy S3, I get uneven frame rates. The frame rate varies between 52-60.9 but is mostly around 60. Unfortunately this means very jittery animation.

There seems to have been some old problem with the Java on Android that somehow handled frame rates but that has long since been fixed. So why do I have a frame rate issue still?

Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: Are you running any heavy updating methods, by any chance?

Comment: No. This is just using even the tutorial example, which does nothing at all as far as I can surmise, other than display the frame-rate.

Comment: From experience, when the device is fast (like Galaxy S3), a 57.0 to 60.0 frame rate is normal. The animation looked normal, though, and little to no jittering is visible. This is assuming "animations" mean sprite animations and/or `CCActions`.

Comment: Why isn't it always 60 if the device is fast like this. Seems like a problem with vertical sync or something.
The funny thing is that I've experienced the same "jitter" on my computer (which is extremely fast) when compiling for linux. This happens on only ONE of my two monitors. On one, the update is exactly 60 fps. On the other I get the same fluctuation around 60 as on the Galaxy S3.

This means that I can actually move the window with the game running from one monitor to the other and see the difference.

Comment: I have the same problem with Galaxy S4 and cocos2d-x 3.2 and jittering is even worse something between 40 and 60 sometimes.